# Can I wait on requesting fancy moderator gear until our site has a design?

Tags: support, design, moderators, t-shirt

I recently became a community moderator on [blender.stackexchange](http://blender.stackexchange.com). SE kindly offered to send some neat moderator gear (shirt and hat), optionally styled with a site-specific design.

Since our site doesn't yet have a site-specific design, (and it's unknown how long it will be before it does), can I wait on asking for the aforementioned items in order to get site-specific gear?

Comment: The hat isn't site specific, so get it anyway. Also you'll have a second set of swag when your site *does* graduate.

Comment: Hey I never got this offer as a pro tempore :(  Actually I know some people at U&L who are still waiting for their unicorn hoodie too.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Oh, send them your sizes and stuff now; you deserve some new clothes.

When the site specific swag exists, let em know Jaydles said you could have the custom tee too, *even though you got the plain one already*.  You can link here for proof; our Swag Fraud Prevention  Department can be an untrusting bunch.

Thanks for all your generosity!

Comment: "Swag Fraud Prevention Department" I'm inclined to believe this is a real department, albeit just the CM's armed with shotguns...

Comment: SFPD - cool acronym!

Comment: Well, even when the site graduates you can wait quite some time for the graduation swag anyway, apparently at least half a year.

Comment: I'm holding out for my "StakXChange" brand designer jeans.